# How to change function name inside managed code while using DllImpot attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to call an external function like this.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT Point);
```

However I want to change function name from `WindowFromPoint` to `MyFunc`.
So in my managed code I would be able to do :

```
MyFunc(new POINT());
```

Because this is not the only function and there is over 100 functions I'm looking for a easy one line solution.

Comment: This is such a drastic bad idea that this has to be an XY question.  The answer to X is to declare your own DLL export in C++ with `extern "C"` or rename it with a .def file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "WindowFromPoint")]
static extern IntPtr MyFunc(POINT Point);
```

I believe this will work.

Or, if, for whatever reason, you need to keep the name you can try this:

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] 
public static IntPtr MyFunc(POINT Point)
{
    return WindowFromPoint(Point);
}
```

Comment: I assume it works for any DLL. I don't see why it wouldn't. You just have to provide the name of the function you need to reference in the `EntryPoint` parameter.